# Lambda Layer of Npm Package for (ARM64 Arch)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, arm64, aws-graviton

I tried creating a AWS Lambda Layer for npm package [Sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) using this [Medium Blog](https://medium.com/@anuragchitti1103/creating-lambda-layer-with-node-js-6a5ecd7c7553) but it is not working for AWS Lambda ARM64 Architecture.

I got this error from lambda function:

```
"Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-arm64v8.node'"
```

I would like to use this AWS Graviton2 processor only.

Can anyone tell me what is missing in this blog post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it by re-building the npm package.

**Step 1:** Create a dir and navigate into it.

```
mkdir layers
cd layers
```

**Step 2:** Create another directory `nodejs`

```
mkdir nodejs
cd nodejs
```

**Step 3:** Install whatever npm pacakges you need

```
npm install package-name
```

**Step 4:** Re-build installed packages for both **x64** and **arm64** arch

```
npm rebuild --platform=linux --arch=x64 package_name
npm rebuild --platform=linux --arch=arm64 package_name
```

**Step 5:** Move back to **layers** directory

```
cd ..
```

**Step 6:** Zip the **nodejs** directory

```
zip -r name_whatever_you_want.zip nodejs
```

All Set!! Now we can upload this as a Lambda Layer